# How to obtain a FMapInterface.In from a FMapInterface.MapsTo and vice-versa?

Tags: dictionary, coq

From the manual [`FMapInterface.In`](https://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.FSets.FMapInterface.html#WSfun.In) is defined as:

```
Definition In (k:key)(m: t elt) : Prop := exists e:elt, MapsTo k e m.
```

So, I was expecting that unfolding a term `In k m` would yield `exists e, MapsTo k e m`.

However, in Coq 8.4pl4, given this:

```
______________________________________(1/1)
In (elt:=t) k m
```

performing an `unfold` yields

```
______________________________________(1/1)
Raw.In0 t (this m)
```

by issuing a `Print M` (where `M` is the module in question) I get

```
Module M
 : Sig 
.
.
. 
   End
:= (FMapAVL.Make ID)
```

My solution is to use lemmas `find_mapsto_iff` and `in_find_iff` (from [`FMapFacts`](https://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.FSets.FMapFacts.html#)), but that seems overly complicated. Why doesn't unfolding the definition work?

Comment: Are you sure the initial In is FMapInterface.In? Can you Set Printing All or something?

Comment: Indeed, it is not the initial FMapInterface.In. It is an instance of FMapAVL.Make (notice the output of `Print M`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance of module `FMapInterface` (obtained from `FMapAVL.Make`) **changes** the definition of `In`, so this basic property is lost in the instance.

Instead, the result must be proved at the level of `FMapInterface`. The solution is to create an auxiliary module with these two properties.

```
Require Coq.FSets.FMapFacts.
Require Coq.FSets.FMapInterface.

Module MapUtil (Import M:FMapInterface.WS).
  Module F := FMapFacts.Facts M.
  Import F.
  Lemma mapsto_to_in:
    forall elt k e m,
    MapsTo (elt:=elt) k e m ->
    In k m.
  Proof.
    intros.
    unfold In.
    exists e.
    assumption.
  Qed.

  Lemma in_to_mapsto : forall (elt:Type) m x,
    In x m -> exists (e:elt), MapsTo x e m.
  Proof.
    intros.
    unfold In in H.
    assumption.
  Qed.
End MapUtil.
```

Using the module above follows the same pattern of using `Coq.FSets.FMapFacts`. For example:

```
Require Import Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx. (* Imports: Nat_as_OT *)
Require Import Coq.FSets.FMapAVL.            (* Imports: FMapAVL.Make *)
Module Map_Nat := FMapAVL.Make Nat_as_OT.    (* Defines a map with nats as keys. *)
Module Map_Nat_Util := MapUtil Map_Nat.      (* Defines an instance of module MapUtil. *)
```